# MySQL Left-Join vs Join with subquery return different results

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

I wrote 2 queries expecting them to yield same results, yet they turned out to be different.

I would like to ask why they return different results?

I am more confident that the 1st query returns what I want, so how should I amend the 2nd query? Thx!

1st SQL query:

```
SELECT 
     Product.*,
     Status.*,
     Price.*
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Status
ON Product.MarketplaceId = Status.ListingId
LEFT JOIN Price
ON Product.ProductId = Price.Id
LIMIT 15;
```

2nd SQL query:

```
SELECT 
     Product.*,
     Status.*,
     Price.*
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Status
ON Product.MarketplaceId IN
(
   SELECT ListingId FROM Status
) 
LEFT JOIN Price
ON Product.ProductId IN
(
    SELECT Id FROM Price
)
LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: You use LIMIT without ORDER BY (which' expression must provide rows uniqueness strictly) - so your queries (both!) are non-deterministic (when total output rows amount is over 15) and cannot guarantee the same outputs even in theory. And 2nd query have no ON clause - so it is not synthactically correct from the point of strict SQL.

Comment: @Akina Thx for replying. Could u further explain why 2nd query has no ON clause? Isn't that I already used two `ON` in the 2nd query? Am I mis-understanding something? Thx a lot!

Comment: *Could u further explain why 2nd query has no ON clause?* I'm sorry, it was a bad look. Forget about last (only) sentence in previous comment, it is errorneous.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data, I don't understand why a different result.  However, if you intend to have only one per product, I would change the second query to use DISTINCT.  If the subquery returns multiple rows for whatever the condition, it will return that many rows even if a single product.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )` if there is an alternative; it is often slower.
- Don't use `LEFT JOIN` if the matching row in the 'right' table will always be there.  It confuses readers.
- The reason for different results is the lack of `ORDER BY`.  (As Akina mentioned.)  Removing the `LIMIT` would probably cause the two queries to deliver all the same rows, though probably in a different order.